# Can I grab the picture of a person from facebook?

Tags: email, facebook, image

I'm trying to grab someones facebook picture from their page while just knowing their email address. I know that the service gravatar.com does this, but a lot of people don't have accounts there so I would like to grab the pictures from facebook. Is this possible? I didn't find anything about this in the developers part of facebook.

Comment: it is programmatically possible. The Outlook plug-in Xobni does it. Not sure how if an agreement with Facebook was required ahead of time.

Answer (score 4):

Programatically? You may not necessarily have the right to use others photographs.  Facebook can because the users have agreed to their T&Cs and uploaded the pictures but I don't think you have any rights concerning the pictures without first contacting the owner.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking of using it just like stackoverflow does it with gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick look at facebook and i've found that when you are logged in to facebook you can search for users based on email address and that will bring back the avatar. i'd be surprised if neither the api nor the FQL supports this functionality since it seems pretty basic.

+1 evernoob on the legality part. altho it is available to you when you're logged in so i can't see why they'd specifically restrict you.

good luck and let us know the results.

N